# Add ng-change on input from code

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I'm generating my controls automatically with this code

```
 var link = function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {
    var view = '';
    var newElem = $("<app-" + $scope.field.type.view + "-component/>");
    newElem.attr("ng-model", "$parent.entity[field.name]");
    newElem.attr("ng-show", "field.visible");
    if ($scope.field.name == "IsBankOfAmerica") {
        newElem.attr("ng-change", "$scope.BOA_Flag($scope.fields)");            
    }
```

but the attribute "ng-change" I want to add it on the input control but it now had added on the div, How can I add on the input?

[image]

Comment: Try this `newElem.find("input").attr("ng-change", "$scope.BOA_Flag($scope.fields)");`

Comment: Thanks @Kaustubh Khare I tried that, but it doesn't show me error, but It doesn't add the attribute.

Comment: Could you make code snippet ?

Comment: `var link = function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {
        var view = '';
        var newElem = $("<app-" + $scope.field.type.view + "-component/>");
        newElem.attr("ng-model", "$parent.entity[field.name]");
        newElem.attr("ng-show", "field.visible");
        if ($scope.field.name == "IsBankOfAmerica") {
            newElem.find("input").attr("ng-change", "$scope.BOA_Flag($scope.fields)");

        }` This is my code now